# Windows store app not running

Tags: c#, msbuild, windows-store-apps

I am using VS Express 2013.

Hi I just created a blank app and then trying to build it. It is giving me this exception.

The "Microsoft.Build.AppxPackage.RemoveDuplicatePayload" task could not be loaded from the     assembly C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.Build.AppxPackage.dll.  Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask

Any idea what is wrong ? It was working for me before. :(

EDIT :

The existing app that I had before are also not running.

Comment: "Confirm that the declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask"
This is what is wrong. :P

Comment: This is just a blank app and I didn't change anything in the code. Shouldn't it run then? Which one in particular you want me to check?

Comment: I would try doing a repair on vs express 2013 if a new project does not run

Comment: I think some files are corrupt. As @KenTucker said you need to repair your installation..

Comment: Me too... same problem occured after installed VisualStudio Ultimate 2013.3